# Redirect user to home page without reloading page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, window, alert

After clicking okay on my `window.prompt` a new tab opens using the code below. I want the user to go to the home page without opening a new tab.

```js
if (window.confirm("Do you really want to leave?")) {
    window.open("./Tutorial2", "Thanks for Visiting!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `window.open()` ***(method)***, will open in a new window. You can use `window.location` ***(object)*** along with `.href = "urladdress"` to redirect your browser to a new url address without opening a new tab.

See the following article on [MDN: Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) for more info.